# how to dual boot win7 and ubuntu 17.04

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-7, ssd, 17.04

I have windows 7 installed on a 120 GB SSD and other than that I have 2 HDD's both 1 tb,I want to install ubuntu on one of the two HDD's. How should I proceed so that I am able to properly dual boot.I had tried it once without much information and ubuntu failed to recognize the win7 installation.

Comment: UEFI or Legacy? what did you actually try?

Comment: UEFI, I installed it from a bootable USB on a partition.

Comment: and you didn't get any errors while installing Ubuntu? and is windows partition (SSD) visible in ubuntu? can you update the question with output of `lsblk`

Comment: currently, I don't have ubuntu installed I did a fresh installation of windows on the SSD, and the SSD was visible when I was installing ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is counter to best practice, but here's how:

1. Create an Ubuntu USB startup stick
2. Boot to the stick
3. Instruct the installer to install into one of the listed 1TB drives.
4. Configure your bios to boot to that 1TB hard drive.
5. Switching back to windows will require you to go back into the BIOS and select the 120GB SSD.

Again - not ideal. At boot time, your motherboard hunts for the device you told it to boot to. Best practice is a true "dual boot" where all OSs live within a single drive. I recommend you shrink the Windows partition and install alongside it inside your primary 120GB SSD. This will allow *grub* to point at either Windows 7 or Ubuntu at each boot. To do this:

1. Create an Ubuntu startup stick
2. Shrink your existing Windows partition enough to fit Ubuntu, maybe 10GB?
3. Instruct the installer to install into one of the blank paritions on the 120GB SSD
4. Reboot - select the OS you want!

Comment: I have an 11GB partition on the SSD will that suffice?

Comment: @RatulChakrabarty  it will but you should probably consider shrinking down windows a little bit more

Comment: thanks for the reply, I had another question, will Linux filesystems degrade the SSD life in any way?

Comment: If you believe my answer to be the best, please select it as such. Additional questions should be asked as separate questions per the community guidelines. That said, NO - the SSD hardware doesn't care what's writing to it. You can ignore the "Made for Windows 10" sticker you're probably referring to. :)